# Tkinter. How to display clock/hourglass using askopenfilename

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter.askopenfilename to open a file that contains logon details for a peripheral device.  My code takes those details and then logs into that device, navigates through a CLI and downloads a configuration image from the peripheral.

This process can take 10 - 15 seconds and I'd like to change the cursor status during this period.  I've found that if I try and open a new window to show an in progress message, the download completes before the dialog is displayed.

Sample code fragment:

```
 filename = askopenfilename(parent=root,filetypes=[("Configured Devices",".cfg")])
 if len(filename) == 0:
    return
 file_list = open(filename,'r')
 for line in file_list:
    line=line.strip()
    line=line.split(",")
    ip=line[0]
    username = line[1]
    password = line[2]
    break
 file_list.close()
 get_config(ip,username,password)  #This logs in and extracts the configuration
```

Comment: Sorry, not working for me.

Comment: I've inserted the "root.config(cursor="wait") before the routine to log into the peripheral (get_config(a,b,c)), however I'm finding that there is so much delay before the cursor status is changed, that the routine completes before the cursor is updated.  I'm running an Intel i-7(2.2 GHz) so I don't think this is necessarily a CPU bandwidth limitation.  The operation does eventually change the cursor (If I omit root.config(cursor="") from after the routine, the cursor does show in the "busy" state, it just doesn't change quickly enough to be useful

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with the same thing.  Not able to find answers that I like and seemed complete.  So here is an example I put together:

```
import tkinter as Tk
import time


class AppWaitCursor(  ):
    """
    Purpose:
        display wait cursor, continue with a blocking task
        and restore cursor
        Here: task is a sleep and print

    This is a bit of a pain as we need 2 methods to implement, could get cleverer
    passing around functions, perhaps closures, partials, or lambdas, that would
    obscure the technique.

    Got something better for the same purpose?  Let me know.

    works but not reliably inside of spyder --
    run from command line
    only tried in windows python 3.8
    """

    #  ----------- init -----------
    def __init__( self,     ):
        self.build_run()      # separate method for easier messing about

# ------------------------------------------
def begin_wait_cursor_task( self,  ):
    """
    this really just sets up the cursor, then calls the rest of the task
    """
    self.root.config( cursor="wait" )   # but not displayed need a refresh
    print( "begin_wait_cursor_task", flush = True)

    # time in ms 20 seems good 2 not so much, idle did not do it for me:
    # this may give the user 20 ms to interact with gui but most will not notice
    # click twice fast and it may then run twice!
    self.root.after( 20 ,     self.continue_wait_cursor_task  )


# ------------------------------------------
def continue_wait_cursor_task( self ):
    """
    """
    print( "continue_wait_cursor_task", flush = True)
    time.sleep( 1 )
    print( "almost there" )
    time.sleep( 1 )
    self.root.config( cursor="" )
    print( "normal cursor\n\n", flush = True)


# ----------------------------------------
def build_run( self):
    """
    build the gui and run it

    """
    self.root       = Tk.Tk()

    a_widget  = Tk.Button( self.root, text="do wait cursor task",     command = self.begin_wait_cursor_task )
    a_widget.pack()

    a_widget  = Tk.Button( self.root, text="do nothing",   )
    a_widget.pack()



    self.root.mainloop()


def ex_cursor0():
    print( """
    ------------------ ex_cursor0 ----------------
    """ )
    app     = AppWaitCursor( )


ex_cursor0()

    enter code here
```

Comment: code did not want to paste in, let me know if it does not run for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `root.config(cursor="wait")` to change the cursor to a busy cursor.